# Word for someone who is never late

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a single word in English that can be used to describe a person who never misses tasks like appointments, deadlines etc.?

Comment: Try "punctual". If you describe a person as "punctual", it will be understood that the person does things on time.

Answer (score 3):

Such a person could be considered ***conscientious***, ***dutiful***, even (my favorite) ***[punctilious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/punctilious)***

Comment: Ok. So, can I use either of these words for a person who gives a ride everyday and never misses this daily task, even this task is a paid one?

Comment: Also, "punctual", if you wanna go for more common words that mean exactly the right thing instead of awesome words that mean roughly the same thing, but one generalization up (good manners in general instead of just punctuality)

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Yes, although the simplest and most direct one is probably *conscientious*.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Perhaps, though I'd say "punctual" applies more to a single instance of being on time, and less to a characteristic of a person who is always on time.

Comment: @JimMack In my experience, at least, describing a person as something suggests that they're always that, not just that one instance. That is, a punctual *arrival* would just be the once, but a punctual *person* always arrives on time.